# Using static library .lib in Shared Items Project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a header and .lib file that I need to use in several projects. I created a Shared Items Project in my VS Solution and added the source files in it. I use `#pragma comment (lib, "library.lib")` but I cannot specify which path should be search to find it the way I can do for a normal project.

So my question is, How can I specify search path in a Visual Studio Shared Item Project?

Thanks